# File resources in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, resources, pyqt, bundle

I got few images and one exe file which I would like to bundle inside of the python exe file?

I mean the same or similar way that it could be done in the visual studio:

[image]

Please tell me if its possible, if so , how could I access the resources then?

I am using pyinstaller if it does matter.

Answer (score -1):

You can't bundle your resources inside .Net runtime. Visual Studio allows you to bundle your resources inside your project exe not inside .net executable.

Same way you cannot bundle resources like images and exe files inside python.exe but using Pyinstaller you can create your project exe which will include your resources.

To create a single file use --onefile flag while bundling your project. As per Pyinstaller documentation -

"In a --onefile distribution, data files are bundled within the executable and then at runtime extracted into the work directory."

Here is a link for [how onefile mode works](http://www.pyinstaller.org/export/v2.0/project/doc/Manual.html#how-one-file-mode-works)

Comment: I am asking for a way to bundle few files though.